# print factors of a number in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to print the factors of the number 20 in python so it goes:
20
10
5
4
2
1

I realize this is a pretty straightforward question, but I just had a question about some specifics in my attempt.  If I say:

```
def factors(n):
    i = n
    while i < 0:
        if n % i == 0:
            print(i)
        i-= 1
```

When I do this it only prints out 20. I figure there's something wrong when I assign i=n and then decremented i, is it also affecting n? How does that work?
Also I realize this could probably be done with a for loop but when I use a for loop I can only figure out how to print the factors backwards so that I get: 1, 2, 5, 10....
Also I need to do this using just iteration. Help?

Note: This isn't a homework question I'm trying to relearn python on my own since it's been a while so I feel pretty silly being stuck on this question :(

Comment: you can start at i=n/2 for a slight performance boost

Comment: @Ben that will be a great performance boost if the n is very large.

Comment: You may get further performance improvement for large values of `n` by using the square root of `n`: `from math import sqrt; i = int(sqrt(n))`. For small values of `n`, this may be less performant, if calculating the square root dominates. But then,  it would be fast enough anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while i < 0:
```

This will be false right from the start, since `i` starts off positive, presumably. You want:

```
while i > 0:
```

In words, you want to "start `i` off at `n`, and decrement it while it is still greater than 0, testing for factors at each step".

---

```
>>> def factors(n):
...     i = n
...     while i > 0:  # <--
...         if n % i == 0:
...             print(i)
...         i-= 1
... 
>>> factors(20)
20
10
5
4
2
1
```

Comment: Thanks I must have been staring at this too long

Comment: I thought of that, but then why does it print out 20 like it says in the question?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Well `i` starts of at `n`, which is 20.

Comment: Yeah, but the while loop would never execute because i would never be < 0 so where does the 20 print?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Oh you mean in the OP's original code; sorry I misunderstood. Yes, the 20 doesn't print in the code the OP has posted.

Comment: More Pythonic would be to eliminate the `while` loop altogether, and use `for i in xrange(n + 1, 1, -1): ...`. Note that `n + 1` is only necessary if you want it to include the number itself as a factor. Otherwise, `n`, `n/2`, or `int(sqrt(n))` would all suffice. Now if you want the *prime* factors of `n`, there are more efficient ways to get them.

Answer (score 0):

The while condition should be `i > 0` and not `i < 0` because it will never satisfy it as i begins in 20 (or more in other cases)

Answer (score 0):

**Hope my answer helps!**

```
#The "while True" program allows Python to reject any string or characters
while True:
try:
    num = int(input("Enter a number and I'll test it for a prime value: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, I didn't get that.")
    continue
else:
    break

#The factor of any number contains 1 so 1 is in the list by default.
fact = [1]

#since y is 0 and the next possible factor is 2, x will start from 2.
#num % x allows Python to see if the number is divisible by x
for y in range(num):
    x = y + 2
    if num % x is 0:
        fact.append(x)
#Lastly you can choose to print the list
print("The factors of %s are %s" % (num, fact))
```